# Conflicting declarations for templates, static variables and whatnot

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, static, g++

I have this source code that I want to compile under g++ 4.4.5. This code compiles properly in Visual C++ 2008 but not with g++.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int MAXSIZE>
class ThreadSafePool
{
    typedef T theType;
};


template<int value>
class CNetPacket
{
    public:
            static const int s_max_pool_cnt=30;
    private:
            static ThreadSafePool<CNetPacket<value>, CNetPacket<value>::s_max_pool_cnt> s_packet_pool;
};

template<int value>
ThreadSafePool<CNetPacket<value>, CNetPacket<value>::s_max_pool_cnt> CNetPacket<value>::s_packet_pool;


int main()
{
    int temp = CNetPacket<300>::s_max_pool_cnt;
}
```

g++ gives this error message:

test.cpp:21: error: conflicting declaration ThreadSafePool, CNetPacket::s_max_pool_cnt> CNetPacket::s_packet_pool

test.cpp:16: error: CNetPacket::s_packet_pool has a previous declaration as ThreadSafePool, 30> CNetPacket::s_packet_pool

test.cpp:21: error: declaration of ThreadSafePool, 30> CNetPacket::s_packet_pool outside of class is not definition

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine for me with gcc 4.7 svn,  gcc 4.6.1, gcc 4.5.3, gcc 4.3.4 and fails with gcc 4.4.2

I think it is a compiler bug.